# Draw a line for a moving marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Below is the code. The code is importing json lat/lng and track from aircraft then display it on a google map with moving markers. What I am wanting to do is add a trail/poly line onlick function so when a user clicks on the marker it show the trail behind it similar to this: (no need for all the colours just one for now unless it is doable :) ) [fr24.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JTUF.jpg). Thanks in advance.

```
 var infoWindows = {};
  var markers = {};
  function getIconForPlane(value) {
  var r = 255, g = 255, b = 0;
return {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    scale: 5,
    fillColor: 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')',
    fillOpacity: 0.9,
    rotation: value.track
    };
}

function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.363, 175.044),
zoom: 5,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}; 
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
 mapOptions);
window.setInterval(readData, 1000);
}

function text(value) {
return '<b>Speed: </b> ' + value.speed + ' <br><b>Flight: </b>' + 
value.flight 
 + 
 '<br><b>Vertical Rate: </b>' + value.vert_rate +'<br><b>Last radar contact: 
 </b>' +value.seen +'<b>s</b>';
window.setInterval(text, 1000);
}

 function createInfoWindow(value, marker, map) {
 var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: text(value)
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   iw.open(map, marker);
 });
return iw;
}

function readData() {
 $.getJSON
 ('https://crossorigin.me/http://radar1.ddns.net:3080/data/aircraft.json
', function(data) {
$.each(data.aircraft, function(i, value) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon, value.flight, 
  value.altitude);
  if (markers[value.hex]) {
    markers[value.hex].setPosition(myLatlng);
    console.log("moving marker for " + value.hex);
infoWindows[value.hex].setContent(text(value));
 } else {
// create new
markers[value.hex] = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  icon: getIconForPlane(value),
  map: map,
  title: "Callsign: " + value.flight + ", Altitude: " + value.altitude
});
console.log("creating marker for " + value.hex);
infoWindows[value.hex] = createInfoWindow(value, markers[value.hex] 
 ,map)
 }
  });
 });
```

}

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something with what you have?

Comment: Hi @John I can't get it to work with jsfiddle but the code above is the whole code :).

Comment: You successfully implemented it ? I wanna do the same moving map for my Prepar3D Thanks

Comment: @bluewonder Nope sadly still looking at ways to do it